# Floating toolbar with text selection controls

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design, textselection

I was researching all over the web to no avail. My app requires a floating toolbar which appears above a selected text because the default text selection controls are not accessible in a particular case and they also show up oddly in my activity with a translucent status bar and without an action bar.
I found this from Google's design guidelines (More precisely from [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/selection.html#selection-text-selection)) and there is no mention on how to do it.

[image: Floating Toolbar]

If someone knows how to make this, or is familiar with a library capable of such, I'd be very much grateful.

Comment: Are you looking to add a popup menu over the highlighted text?

Comment: The popup menu isn't necessary, just the ordinary Cut/Copy/Paste actions. I want that floating toolbar to simply replace the selection controls which normally appear in the action bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Android Support Library revision 22.2, be aware that floating toolbars are not backward-compatible and appcompat takes control over ActionMode objects by default.

so this will only work on Android-M preview you can test by creating AVD M-preview emulator.

Here this link shows [Behavior change](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-test-selection)

Comment: Thank you! Finally Google has brought us the floating toolbars. I've moved from the design I had before and I longer require them. However, thanks to you I now know that it finally exists and can be implemented with no hassle.

Comment: @BenFaingold How can I implement it pre android M devices?